# php.ini to write for home/xyz to be home/c?q=xyz

Tags: php, redirect, web, url-rewriting

How to write php.ini such that

> home/xyz/

means

> home/c/index.php?q=xyz

Without creating xyz directory.

Comment: You're probably looking to use a mod rewrite http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/ and http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: do you mean it can be done by htaccess?

Comment: It can. You can further your research using "mod rewrite htaccess".

Comment: @Fred-ii- already i invested my 24 hours for this but i didn't get it.
so can you write a small code for above

Comment: Sorry, I can't. Mod rewrites aren't my *forté*. I only assist in comments when it comes to questions like these.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)/?$ /home/c/index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

This should redirect all non existing files/directories in home/

EDIT: removing trailing slash

Comment: DirectoryIndex index.php
DirectorySlash Off
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!c/).*)$ c/$1 [L,NC]

Comment: i already have this file written Which is working properly if i make folder(xyz)  and write index.php as include '../index.php'
but as xyz can be anything and i can not create so much folders
i need something which can make it easy

Comment: Now 
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: this is for every image i have

Comment: Do you have set header Content-type ?

Comment: nope
where to set
i don't know anything about htaccess
i just google it

Comment: I mean header in php, which serve the images. I suppose you load image in php and print it. If so, you have to write command header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); or any image type you are using